# Can't push to heroku Rails 6. No command webpacker found/precompiling assets failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets, webpacker

When I run

```
git push heroku master
```

I get this:

```
3d03d9a9bed492eab33bdbd65f7.css
remote:        I, [2020-11-22T00:08:54.351994 #1614]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_9cb71dd2/public/assets/rebel-99a5cf4009e103727878a62db3995432aec733d03d9a9bed492eab33bdbd65f7.css.gz
remote:        Compiling...
remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        yarn run v1.22.4
remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        error Command "webpack" not found.
remote:        
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

I've searched everywhere what the heck is going on? How do I fix this? Thank!

Comment: "error Command "webpack" not found"—that seems clear, doesn't it? Are you depending on `webpack` in your `package.json`?

Comment: I have the webpacker gem, I am not sure what package,json is for or how to use it. Sorry I am a N00b